# De Broglie wavelength

Tags: homework-and-exercises, wavelength

Ok so the question is: an electron of kinetic energy E has de Broglie wavelength λ. What is the de Broglie wavelength of an electron with kinetic energy 2E.

I keep getting the answer as λ/2 but the correct answer is λ/sqrt 2

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Welcome to PSE @m.bazza. Your question classifies as a homework type question and unfortunately, homework question are not answered here. You should add your efforts and ask about a specific concept that may be related to the question.

Comment: You never wrote down the formula you used. Doesn't the correct answer suggest you may well have used a wrong one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the equation for the de Broglie wavelength for an electron of momentum p:

\begin{equation}
\lambda=\frac{h}{p}
\end{equation}

where $h$ is Planck's constant. We know the kinetic energy, and thus we can solve for the momentum:

\begin{align}
E&=\frac{1}{2}mv^2\notag \\
&=\frac{p^2}{2m}\notag\\
\rightarrow p&=\sqrt{2mE}
\end{align}

Plugging this solution into our equation for the de Broglie wavelength, we obtain
\begin{equation}
\lambda=\frac{h}{\sqrt{2mE}}
\end{equation}

What happens when you double the kinetic energy $E$? I think you can take it from here.